# How to rectify the errors in resources files of a form in C#

Tags: c#

I get this error

> Error  1   The item "obj\Debug\myproject.Form1.resources" was specified more than once in the "Resources" parameter.  Duplicate items are not supported by the "Resources" parameter.

This error I got while merging two different projects that I did using windows application.

Is there a method to rectify this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open up your .csproj project file in any text editor and search for `obj\Debug\myproject.Form1.resources`.  You'll probably find more than one reference.  Just delete the duplicates until only one is left.